# PHP remove information from string

Tags: php, string

I have a string that contains an image in html format. Ie..

```
<img title="imagetitle1" src="www.example.com/image1.gif" height="420" width="340" />
```

I need to strip everything from it with the exception of the url of the src. Since we don't know what the title will be and thus cannot use `str_replace`, how do we do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex, you can do this:

```
$input = '<img title="imagetitle1" src="www.example.com/image1.gif" height="420" width="340" />';

if (preg_match('/src\\=\\"(.*?)\\"/m', $input, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
} 

//output
www.example.com/image1.gif
```

Answer (score 3):

When parsing HTML data, I like to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of a RegEx.

```
$data = 'Test data src="A" <img title="imagetitle1" src="www.example.com/image1.gif" height="420" width="340" />More data';
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($data);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$img = $xPath->query('//img[@title="imagetitle1"]');
echo $img->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/bv6Ivnuy